# How would I output the results to html index page - NodeJS - Html

Tags: html, node.js

Here is the index.html file I want to display the results from my Javascript file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hera-Anime-Dl</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Hera-Anime-Dl</h1>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="animeInput"=> Insert a anime title</input>
    <input type="text" id="episodeInput"=> Insert a episode number</input>
<button onclick="test()">search</button>

<p id="title"></p>
<p id="number"></p>
<div id="output"></div>

<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the app.js file when I use console.log it outputs results so I want to display the results on the index not just in the console I want the results from the console.log to be displayed to the html page or just have it display on the index.html page

```
function test(){
    const ConsoleLogHTML = require('console-log-html');
    const anime = require('anime-dl')

    let animeInput = document.getElementById("animeInput").value;
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = animeInput;
    let episodeInput = document.getElementById("episodeInput").value;
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = episodeInput;

    const name = animeInput
    const chapter = episodeInput
    anime.getLinksByNameAndChapter(name, chapter).then(console.log)

   }
```

I am using the anime-dl NPM package and want to get the result to display on the index.html page

here is what the anime-dl output for the search anime looks like [I want to grab information from this output and display it to the index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpFP5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace console.log to a function that will recieve the response of the query as parameter, for example:

ES6

```
anime.getLinksByNameAndChapter(name, chapter).then((response)=>{
    document.getElementById("output").innerHtml = response.title
})
```

ES5

```
anime.getLinksByNameAndChapter(name, chapter).then(function(response){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHtml = response.title
})
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more if you can.

Comment: How would I do, sorry if you add me on discord - ̗̀ Hera ̖́-#0002

Comment: @Z3rfythegod I have added ES5 code, I hope you can understand it, if still cant understand take a look to [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and [JSON objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON). I dont have discord account

Comment: can you make a discord?

Comment: I just created a chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158011/z3rfy-the-god

Comment: I cannot talk in the chat room as I do not have 20+ rep